# Vertex Shader and Color of the Original Model

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, vertex-shader

I am currently building a vertex shader to perform a very simple rotation around z-axis over a 3-D model. The 3-D model is originally well colored. But after I add the shader I wrote, it screw up the original color. I have no idea why, because I assume that vertex shader should not touch the color part.

What I want is just transform the vertex, and in the mean time, the color keep the original.

The shader is here, I name it "shader.cpp":

```
void main() {
   float PI = 3.14159265358979323846264;
   float angle = 45.0;
   float rad_angle = angle*PI/180.0;

   vec4 a = gl_Vertex; 
   vec4 b = a;
   b.x = a.x*cos(rad_angle) - a.y*sin(rad_angle);
   b.y = a.y*cos(rad_angle) + a.x*sin(rad_angle);
   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*b;
}
```

Actually, this is just a very simple shader copied from the official site of OpenGL GLSL.

I load the shader with the following code, notice readShader(const char*) is a method to read the content of the file shader.cpp. It is very trivial so I don't put it here(Pretty sure the it works fine):

```
void shading() {

   GLuint shader, prog;
   const GLchar * shaderText = readShader("shader.cpp");
   shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
   glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderText, NULL);
   glCompileShader(shader);

   prog = glCreateProgram();
   glAttachShader(prog, shader);
   glLinkProgram(prog);
   glUseProgram(prog);
}
```

Then, there is a display() function in the original code, which build the 3D graph. I then add the shading() function at the front of the display(). Like this:

```
void display(void) {
     shading();
    //....
}
```

Of course the display function is called by the GLUT lib function as:

```
glutDisplayFunc(display);
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why is it called shader.cpp when it's not a C++ source file?

Comment: Also, which OpenGL version are you using?

Comment: I think you have to pass color information from VS to FS with something like: `gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;` (in the VS)

Comment: @immibis: No `#version` directive so `110` is implied.

Comment: Why aren't you checking the shader compilation and link logs?  Hell, even the compilation/link *status*?

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @immibis I just name is shader.cpp, actually, the extension name does not matter, for what I need is just a string of code

Comment: @genfault the status of compile/linking is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a vertex shader by itself. When using the programmable pipeline, you need to have both a vertex shader and a fragment shader.

From section 3.9 "Fragment Shaders" in the OpenGL 3.3 spec:

> When the program object currently in use includes a fragment shader, its fragment shader is considered active, and is used to process fragments. If the program object has no fragment shader, or no program object is currently in use, the results of fragment shader execution are undeﬁned.

This means that you will have to add a fragment shader so that you can use your vertex shader.

Comment: Right, I wrote a fragment shader for that, but I still cannot get what I want. Well, here is the case, the color of the model is defined in the OpenGL code. I just want to use the GLSL to do some transform like rotate. But when I apply the shader, it screw up the originally defined color. Is that abnormal?